# how create zip file for --py-files dependency

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I Have a small project where I need to run Spark-submit with python code. here is the code [link](https://github.com/jeevan530/pyspark-example).

```
[XXXXX pysparktest]$ ls
README.md  spark_sample.py  utils
```

If I run this code with below spark-submit it is successful.

```
$ spark-submit spark_sample.py
```

But, I want to make utils package as zip file and pass zipfile to spark submit with help of --py-files

```
[XXXXXX pysparktest]$ ls
README.md  spark_sample.py  utils.zip

[XXXXXX pysparktest]$ spark-submit --py-files utils.zip spark_sample.py
```

When I tried ziping utils package directly and run through spark-submit I'm getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mapr/pysparktest/spark_sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils import SparkOperations
ImportError: No module named utils
```

Can any one help me how to make the zip file and pass the zip file with --py-files parameter.

Comment: Hey Jeevan, Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: hi Amm, not yet